# html5 video detect end then play in reverse? JQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, html5-video

I have limited knowledge on JS/JQuery but I am wondering if you can detect the end of a HTML5 video and then Play the video in reverse and then play it from the start so basically an endless loop playing forwards and then backwards?

Using JQuery/Javascript

Answer (score 7):

Streaming video codecs are optimised to be played forward so, while there is a `playbackRate` property of HTML5 video which you might be able to use to reverse the playback of your video (try setting it to -1), the result is probably not going to be particularly satisfactory.

A better approach would be to create an additional video at the encoding stage which runs in reverse. You could then use the video's `ended` event to toggle the source back and forward between the forward and reversed videos.

Or as Ken, has helpfully suggested in the comments, create a single video in which the sequence is played forward and then in reverse. You can then set the video to loop and you've got what you're after.

Just for your reference, the w3 have quite a handy [example](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) which allows you to explore in real time the various methods, properties and events available in HTML5 video.

Comment: Or just merge the two versions into one and loop it. The data will be about the same (one header and one request less).